# Answer is coming different in Math.ceil() in java?

Tags: java, methods, ceil

When I use `0.0 +` in `Math.ceil()` method in below code, the answer with `op=1` and `cl=11` is 7 which is correct.

```java
 (int)(Math.ceil((0.0 + op) / 2) + Math.ceil((0.0 + cl) / 2))
```

But when I don't use `0.0 +` then the answer is 5.

Can anybody please help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because without `0.0` the expression `op / 2` applies to integer values and produce an integer: `1/2` would return `0` as integer, NOT `0.5`.

Using `0.0 +`, you are forcing the 1st operand to be a double and the division then operates on doubles and `1.0 / 2` will give `0.5` as expected.

*Note: another (preferred) way would be to explicit cast your operand to double rather than using the `0.0 +` trick.*

Comment: Also, instead of using 0.0, OP can divide by 2.0 too